# composer says my php version is 7.3 but i am already installing php 8.0.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am working with a laravel framework and use composer to install a specific version of packages but I am getting an error form composer as following

```
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.12". You are running 7.3.11. in /Users/mac/Documents/laravel_projects/covid_site/demo_1/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
```

but when I run php info from xampp it says my php version is 8.0.2 as following image
[image]

how I can solve this issue ?

> I am using mac OS

Comment: try to run `which php`

Comment: `php --version` in a terminal. There are CLI and webserver versions of PHP. Your image shows the webserver one

Comment: php -v return it's 7.3

Comment: i will check the link you sent and reply you

Comment: Well yes, that's what the message says: "_You are running 7.3.11_"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have two different php version for your setup. The webserver uses a different version than your CLI.

To verify the behavior type `php --version`. Is the output not the desired php-version check your global `$PATH` variable.

```
echo $PATH # for linux/macos
echo %PATH% # for winodws
```

Maybe you see the path to your old version here.

To fix this issue [just replace](https://superuser.com/a/949577/1112639) the old php path with your newer one.

Comment: what is the path i should add to PATH variables ?

Comment: What is the current value? I guess `/Applications/XAMPP/php` should be the right path.