# After 'composer install', composer says the php version is different. How do I solve it?

Tags: php

I've tried several attempts and the results are all unsuccessful.
[composer says my php version is 7.3 but i am already installing php 8.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784451/composer-says-my-php-version-is-7-3-but-i-am-already-installing-php-8-0-2)

I've seen some posts in the same situation as me, but it didn't solve anything at all.

this is my test server error code

```
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.4.23. in /home/vagrant/code/interproindigo/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
```

But when I run php -v, the php version is 8.0.9 as follows

`PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2021 13:03:39) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v8.0.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: do you use Linux? do you have PHP 8.0 installed?

Comment: If you are using Linux and have PHP 8.0 in your device,  run: sudo update-alternatives --config php, and then choose PHP 8.0

Comment: Given that your projects seems to run in vagrant, are you sure the two commands are run in the same environment? If you run the `php -v` on your machine and composer in vagrant (or vice-versa) this could explain it.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config php did not solve it, and when I input the php -v command on the real server, `PHP 7.4.29 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2022 10:55:38) ( NTS )` is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because the php version of the real server and the test server did not match.
`php7.4 -f /usr/local/bin/composer update`
Entering this code solved the problem.